# TestNG expectedExceptions throws TestException

Tags: java, testng, expected-exception

I am trying to test the following class:

```
package com.myclass;
public class MyClass {
    private Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void extractInfoFromLine(String line) throws InvalidInputException {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        if (dataMap.containsKey(words[0])) {
            throw new InvalidInputException();
        }
        dataMap.put(words[0], words[2]);
    }
    public void confirmInfoPresent(String name) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Using this TestNG class:

```
package com.myclass;
public class MyClassTest {
    private MyClass myClass;

    @DataProvider(name = "invalid-data-provider")
    public Object[][] invalidDataProvider() {
        return new Object[][] { 
                { "A is B", "A"},
                { "A is D", "A"},
        };
    }

    @BeforeTest()
    public void setup() {
        myClass = new MyClass();
    }
    @Test(dataProvider = "invalid-data-provider", expectedExceptions = InvalidInputException.class)
    public void testExceptionalExtractValueForKey(String line, String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        myClass.extractInfoFromLine(line);
        myClass.confirmInfoPresent(name);
    }
}
```

I have defined the following custom exception for this:

```
package com.myclass;
public class InvalidInputException extends Exception {
    public InvalidInputException() {
        super();
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public InvalidInputException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

However, when I run this test case, I get the following error:

```
Expected exception com.myclass.InvalidInputException but got org.testng.TestException: 
Method MyClassTest.testExceptionalExtractValueForKey(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.myclass.MyClassTest@3930015a] should have thrown an exception of class com.myclass.InvalidInputException
```

I tried replacing my custom exception with a standard exception and still got the same result.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Your code doesn't throw an exception at all.

Comment: @thefourtheye: When I try to debug, it goes to the line `throw new InvalidInputException();` and never returns back to my class after that.

Comment: Found that this does not happen when I don't use the `DataProvider`. But the code does not seem to have any issues.. :(

Comment: Your code does not throw exception. Map is empty, so there is no "A" key. TestNg says that it expected "InvalidInputException" to be thrown; but didn't get it. So, it throws it's own "TestException" and threats the test as failed. Add "A" key to your dataMap (e.g. dataMap.put("A", "A") right after Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();) and your test will be green. 
From Testng doc: The list of exceptions that a test method is expected to throw. If no exception or a different than one on this list is thrown, this test will be marked a failure.

Comment: @user1058106: I did a line-by-line debug of the code using Eclipse and I can see that the line `throw new InvalidInputException();` is getting executed. So, it is not because of the exception not being thrown. Also, it still does not explain how replacing the data provider with two sequential calls works fine.

Comment: @KarthickS, If you absolutely sure that the code you debug is completely equal to one you posted in your question, then it's just kind of a magic :).
Did you try to add "dataMap.put("A", "A")" after "Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();" ?

Comment: You have never assigned/added anything to datamap . What are you checking ? How will datamap contains come as true

Comment: @user1058106, @Shamik. You are right. This code is example code modeled on my production code. However, I found one thing I had missed out during the conversion to sharable code: `dataMap` should be a member variable. However, the issue does not get fixed because of this. :(

Comment: @user1058106, Shamik the issue happens only when I enter the same test case twice with inputs from the dataProvider. If I change the test to accept to inputs at the same time and do the processing then it does not happen. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @KarthickS, You will have 1 failed and 1 passed test if "dataMap" will be a class member. That's how the code you posted works in Java. It just CAN'T work another way. The only thing I can assume is that "dataMap" location is not the only missed part of your production code.

Comment: @user1058106, yes it was one success and one failure. But why would that be so?

Answer (score 0):

@KarthickS, three different people gave you same answer already. I don't understand what else should be explained and how.
On the first @Test iteration dataMap is empty (`dataMap.containsKey(words[0]) == false`), so, the code inside "if" statement body will not be executed; which means that your exception **will not be thrown**. 
TestNg will threat the test as failed since there is "expectedExceptions" attribute set in your @Test annotation. The second test iteration will pass since dataMap is not empty anymore (`dataMap.put(words[0], words[2]`) - you've added data on the first run).
Once again, TestNg doc says about "expectedExceptions": *The list of exceptions that a test method is expected to throw. If no exception or a different than one on this list is thrown, this test will be marked a failure.*